# writing complex query in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I want to write complex query in mongodb using following fields :

- class
- rate
- hrs

the query should return me result sets based upon the following conditions:

1) `class = "a" && rate > "20000"`

OR

2) `class = "b" && (rate X hrs X 52) > "20000"`

The records in the collection am trying to query looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "3434sfsf",
    "rate": "60",
    "class": "a"
},
{
    "_id": "sdsdsd",
    "rate": "60",
    "class": "b",
    "hrs": "8"
}
```

How can I write my query to achieve what am looking for... Thanks!

Comment: mongo [$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt) works in `number` field and as per your document structure you should change `rate and hrs` to `number`  so you can easily combing `and,or,$gt` in query

Comment: Can you pls help me in writing the query for this...

Comment: in this multiplication `rate X hrs X 52` what the value of `rate and hrs`?

Comment: As mentioned in the document structure... For ex - rate : 60, hrs: 8

Comment: is possible to changed `rate and hrs` to number ?

Answer (score 4):

Please Try the below query :

**Step 1** : we are filtering only those documents with "class" :  "a" OR "class" : "b" and "hrs" key **exists**.

**Step 2** :  we are doing multiplication of "rate" , "hrs" with 52 and storing the result in the key "**rateMultiply**"

**Step 3** : we are filtering the documents on the below mentioned criteria : ***class = "a" && rate > "20000" OR class = "b" && (rate X hrs X 52) > "20000"***

**Step 4** : we are displaying the documnets with only those fields which we need.

Lets create a collection " **exp4** " and insert the below documents :

```
db.exp4.insert({ "_id" : "3434sfsf", "rate" : 60, "class" : "a" });
db.exp4.insert({ "_id" : "sdsdsd", "rate" : 60, "class" : "b", "hrs" : 8 });
db.exp4.insert({ "_id" : "123", "rate" : 30000, "class" : "a", "hrs" : 8 });
db.exp4.insert({ "_id" : "12567", "rate" : 12000, "class" : "b" });
```

Now lets QUERY the collection :

```
db.exp4.aggregate([
     { $match: 
       {$or : [ {"class" : "a"},
                {$and : [{"class":"b"},{"hrs": {"$exists" : 1}}]}
              ]
       }
     },
     { $project : 
        { rateMultiply : { $multiply: ["$rate","$hrs",52]}, 
         rate:1, class:1, hrs : 1 
        } 
     },
     { $match : 
       {$or : [ 
                { $and : [ {"class" : "a"} , 
                           {"rate" : {"$gt" : 20000}} 
                         ] 
                } , 
                { $and : [ {"class" : "b"}, 
                           {rateMultiply: {$gt:20000}}
                         ]
                 } 
               ] 
       }
     },
     { $project: {class : 1 , rate : 1 , hrs : 1 }
     }
  ])
```

RESULT :

```
{ "_id" : "sdsdsd", "rate" : 60, "class" : "b", "hrs" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "123", "rate" : 30000, "class" : "a", "hrs" : 8 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's check your document structure looks like following way where `rate` and `hrs` in number

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a2979e"), "rate" : 60, "class" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a2979f"), "rate" : 60, "class" : "b", "hrs" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a297a0"), "rate" : 30000, "class" : "a", "hrs" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a297a1"), "rate" : 3000, "class" : "b", "hrs" : 8 }
```

Then first you should calculate multiplication of `rate and hrs` separately using `aggregation and multiplication` [$mulitiply](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) takes parameter `rate,hrs and 52` to calculate multiply value as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$project": {
    "multiply": {
        "$multiply": ["$rate", "$hrs", 52]
    },
    "rate": 1,
    "class": 1
}
})
```

so documents looks like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a2979e"), "rate" : 60, "class" : "a", "multiply" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a2979f"), "rate" : 60, "class" : "b", "multiply" : 24960 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a297a0"), "rate" : 30000, "class" : "a", "multiply" : 12480000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c105d097658f88b5a297a1"), "rate" : 3000, "class" : "b", "multiply" : 1248000 }
```

contains new key `multiply` now used this `multiply` in `$match` with `$or and $and` as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "multiply": {
            "$multiply": ["$rate", "$hrs", 52]
        },
        "rate": 1,
        "class": 1
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{
            "$and": [{
                "class": "a"
            }, {
                "rate": {
                    "$gt": 20000
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "$and": [{
                "class": "b"
            }, {
                "multiply": {
                    "$gt": 20000
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
})
```